# Is there an equivalent Namespace for Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, reference, namespaces

I am converting an old vb.net project into c# code and came across a certain Namespace

```
Interaction. MsgBox(„my text here“)
```

The method belongs to the namespace Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction and I was wondering if there is an equivalent in C# or in a more “general“ namespace. It seems to me, that this project is mostly for vb projects and I was wondering if its considered bad style using visual basic references in a C# project.

Of course, I could just use the vb.net namespace, but I wondered if there’s a better or more general solution to this.

Best regards.

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox` ?

Comment: For the record, the namespace is `Microsoft.VisualBasic` and `Interaction` is a module in that namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually indicative that someone upgraded a VB6 application to VB.Net and did the *bare minimum* to make it work.

There is a *standard* [`MessageBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx) control that both C# and VB.Net *should* use. Most other classes/controls/methods in the VB specific libraries also have *standard* replacements, which should have already been adapted to.

Anything from the VB library that involves UI work will be roughly equivalent to WinForms code so you should seek replacements in the [`System.Windows.Forms` namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: i figured that i could use System.Windows.Forms, do you have any idea why there is no standard wpf messageBox? It also seemed quite strange to me, that wpf applications, still use the old winforms?

Comment: @yRadwan - you mean like [`System.Windows.MessageBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602949.aspx)?

Comment: @yRadwan : `System.Windows.MessageBox` is the standard WPF message box.

Comment: @yRadwan and this is why you should tag your question with `wpf` or `winforms`

Comment: "It also seemed quite strange to me, that wpf applications, still use the old winforms". They don't.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever In your post you mentioned System.Windows.Forms twice, and in one of your comments you mentioned System.Windows.MessageBox. I am a little bit confused, which one is the standard messageBox C# and VB.net should use?

Comment: @yRadwan - `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox` is the WinForms standard message box. `System.Windows.MessageBox` is the WPF one. Since all of the VB library UI stuff will tend to use WinForms functionality behind the hood, it's the *closer* of the two. It was only in your first comment that it became somewhat apparent that not only did someone do a bare minimum upgrading VB6 to VB.Net, but they also apparently switched *some* of it over to WPF rather than WinForms. Go with whichever one "matches" the rest of your application.